# Java wrong timezone

Tags: java, timezone, soapui

As can be seen below, system time and SoapUI's time value is different.

[image: system and soapui time]

SoapUI using JRE time and that's why it should be a bug of Java's itself because; *also below code* gives: `Venezuela Time`

```
String tzn = TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName();
System.out.println(tzn);
```

**What I've tried and failed:**

- Playing with regedit and changing time zone then get it back to correct.
- Giving `-Duser.timezone="Europe/Istanbul"` at Control Panel/Java/JRE Settings/Runtime Parameters or giving same parameter inside the `JAVA_OPTS` variable.
- Changing time or time zone and get it back.

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106525/java-incorrect-timezone) surely, correcting the timezone programmatically is doable but I need to correct SoapUI's timezone which affects automated test results. Because tests are time dependent.

Comment: So you see the problem when you're just running a test Java program completely independently of SoapUI? If that's the case, I don't see how SoapUI is relevant to the question.

Comment: Nope not only Java, I am running Soap requests, Http requests, Groovy codes as well. Also some situations requires to trace SoapUI logs.

Comment: Are you sure that Europe/Turkey is a defined timezone? Could you try setting it with Europe/Istanbul? According to this article http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html Europe/Turkey is not defined.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı Could you please clarify your answer to the above question?  Let me re-state it:  On this same system, if you put your 2 lines of java code above (the ones that print the default timezone) into a stand-alone program, does the program output Venezuelan Time or Turkish time?

Comment: @bhdrkn I tried Europe/Istanbul. I typed it wrong in the question it's not working.

Comment: I am not sure that changing the value of "Control Panel/Java/JRE Settings/Runtime Parameters" will have any affect here.  I think that setting is only for the Java browser plug-in.  What you are really interested in is the java.exe instance that is used to launch SOAP-UI.  I believe all SOAP-UI scripting runs within that same VM instance.

Comment: @EJK I agree with you. SoapUI has it's own JRE folder there must be a file that should be edited. But also Groovy scripts are doing some db checks and these values are returning wrong as well. I also checked db sysdate and it's correct so hard to figure out why.

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAlmalı I will ask again.  Could you please respond to the question that has been asked by me and Jon Skeet?  See the 1st and 4th comments.  Without this information, it will be very hard to know the root cause.

Comment: Could you try to set JAVA_OPTS environment var which includes -Duser.timezone="Europe/Istanbul"?

Comment: Ok when i'll be home i'm going to try.

Comment: @EJK I think i answered Jon Skeet's and your question. I am not using only a test Java program or code that I have typed in question not only those giving me the unexpected results. I am running Groovy codes Web Service requests too and if SoapUI's own logs are giving wrong times how can people think SoapUI is relevant from this question?

Comment: 2 lines of code and SoapUI logs are giving same result Venezuelan time

Comment: Edit on comment *irrelevant from this question

Comment: @bhdrkn setting JAVA_OPTS not working pal..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really tried hard to solve this issue, for days. I really don't know why the most plausible two methods are not working properly which:

- Creating `JAVA_OPTS` system variable which has the value of: `-Duser.timezone="Turkey"`
- Passing vm parameter from command line.

At last I gave up and set this parameter for each specific program, to be able to do this for SoapUI, go to `SoapUI Home Path/bin` folder and right click to `soapui-pro.bat` and choose to edit. (If you are using the community version, the name of the bat file will be different)

Then go to line 29 which starts with set `JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128m...` and insert time-zone parameter: `-Duser.timezone="Turkey"`. Now execute the bat file, it's going to start to work properly!

Comment: This isn't a problem just with SoapUI but with JRE/JVM (6 in my case). Our app was having the same issue with Turkey's timezone. Your solution worked for me!