# Timezone value changes per JDK version

Tags: java, timezone

When I have compiled and runned following code statement at the same machine, I am getting two different timezone values.

```
public class TimeZoneDemo {
   public static void main( String args[] ){

  // create time zone object     
  TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();

  // checking time zone value     
  System.out.println(timezone);
   }    
}
```

**JDK 1.6.35**

```
Tue Sep 24 06:25:03 VET 2013
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Caracas",offset=-16200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=5,lastRule=null]
```

**JDK 1.7.02**

```
Tue Sep 24 22:56:54 MAGT 2013
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Magadan",offset=43200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=66,lastRule=null]
```

**OS:** Window 7 64 Bit.

Comment: What machine do you use, with which operating system? (Windows, Mac, Linux, ...)

Comment: And what is your actual location, as configured on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found similar issue, [java incorrect timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106525/java-incorrect-timezone)
As I expected, there is bug about the issue, and already resolve with current version of JDK

Answer (score 1):

The timezone is set against the JVM not the JDK.  You set this against the jvm with...

```
Duser.timezone="Europe/Sofia"
```

If you pass this to the JVM you'll always have the same timezone when you change versions.

The oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) on `TimeZone.getDefault()` mentions...

> Gets the default TimeZone for this host. The source of the default
>   TimeZone may vary with implementation.

Comment: I agree setting `-Duser.timezone` as JVM argument. But JVM must default to the system time zone in the absence of `-Duser.timezone` whatever the implementation/version?

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the following table you will see what updates have been done to the JRE version.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html

The version 1.6.35 is newer than the version 1.7.02. However, it is still possible that one of these environments has been updated with the TZUpdater.

Since only you know where your computer is located only you know whether there is a relevent change.

Comment: I do not think so, since I have tested same code statement at different machine newly formatted, it works fine.

Comment: @mmc18: What do you mean with “I do not think so”? My answer does not contain any statement that you could put into question.

Comment: TZUpdater is runned when there is Day Light Time value or it time is changed. I am sure that there is any change in the location where I am interested. I think there is a bug in JVM.

Comment: @mmc18: As long as you are still unable to answer the question where your computer is located, i.e. which timezone you expect, you should not talk about bugs in the JVM. And again, *JDK 1.7.02* is damn old the current version is *Java SE 7u40*.

Comment: The reason why new version Java SE is released is to clean the bug and add new features. Right, So I have right to doubt in having Java SE bug.

Answer (score 0):

These problems come and go, and no reasonable solution.  See more here: [Java incorrect time zone bug on Windows](http://baruchyoussin.com/java-incorrect-time-zone-bug-windows.html)

*Edit:* Answering Andrew Arnold: In brief, Java runtime has hard time doing the job of correctly finding out the current time zone on the computer.

Windows registry information on the time zones has been unreliable, and the same for native windows API which relies on msvcrt.dll and various msvcrxx.dll .  There is also Managed (.NET) API which requires installing a certain version of .NET Framework which contradicts portability of Java.

Thus, developers of Java runtime have hard time with the current time zone on Windows, and this may continue until Microsoft has some reason to cooperate.