# Date Conversion in Spring is one day off

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, time

I have a POST end-point that takes a couple of values, one being endDate and startDate. When the JSON posts in as:

```
{ "startDate" : "2015-01-30", "endDate" : "2015-12-30" }
```

Spring converts it to a java.util.Date Object that is always one day behind. In the logs I see:

```
Validating that startDate Thu Jan 29 16:00:00 PST 2015 < endDate Tue Dec 29 16:00:00 PST 2015
```

So it got the timezone correct. I had assumed it was related to UTC conversions, but I'm not sure how to configure this or modify it so that it converts it using the proper off-set. The timestamp portion of it isn't required - I only care that the year, day, and month match what is passed in.

if it matters, I'm using Spring (happened with 4.0.6 and 4.1.7) and a POST

Comment: please tell me what do you want

Comment: I want Spring to create a java.util.Date object that has "Thu Jan 30 XX:XX:XX PST 2015" for "2015-01-30" versus what it's doing now. I'm assuming there's a config setting that I'm missing. I don't understand why it's assuming 1/30/2015 UTC and then converting back to my time.

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106525/java-incorrect-timezone

Hope it helps.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: I am seeing the same issue.  The date in PostMan shows as "2013-01-30" but Date variable is assigned Tue Jan 29 16:00:00 PST 2013 so it is one day off.  The problem is I cannot switch to LocalDate due to legacy issues so I am forced to use java Date.  The other reason is that JSF version we use does not support LocalDate

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-30" )
```

## Use the right data type for the job

You are trying to fit a date-only value into a date-time type, `java.util.Date`. [Square peg, round hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole). While trying to come up with a time-of-day to associate with your date, a time zone is being injected, hence your problem.

## `LocalDate`

Solution:

- Never use the terrible old legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`. Use only the modern *java.time* classes.
- For a date-only value, use `LocalDate`.

Your input string happens to be in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-30" ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want a moment, a date with a time-of-day, let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day. Never assume that moment is 00:00:00. In some zones on some dates it may be another time such as 01:00:00 because of anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

```
ZonedId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;     // Let java.time determine the first moment of that date in that zone.
```

## `Instant`

To adjust from to UTC (same moment, different wall-clock time), extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust to UTC. Same moment, same simultaneous point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with  "@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") 
 public Date birthdate;", in my Spring model, where Date is java.sql.Date, will I still be able to use @JsonFormat with LocalDate?

Comment: @DevinAndresSalemi You should not be using `java.sql.Date` anymore, never again. For a date without time, use `LocalDate` class. I do not know where you got `@JsonFormat` but any decent framework should be updated for the *java.time* classes by now. See the table graphic I added.

Comment: I see, thanks, the motive was to use CallableStatement which requires Date, but basically I just need to use Spring Boot to persist a date to SQL Server, using a lot of stored procedures and raw JDBC

Comment: Ended up using CallableStatement.SetObject and LocalDate, works perfect now!

Answer (score 3):

```
String str="2015-01-30";
try{
    SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    Date date = isoFormat.parse(str);
    System.out.println(date);
}catch(ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If I pass it in as a string and convert to a date, there's no problem - it all works. It's when Spring does the conversion that there is a problem. So I start with java.util.Date and I need to convert it to one where the millis from  epoch is centered around my timezone and not UTC

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder how to customize automatic Spring conversion:

```
@Controller
public class MyFormController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    }
    // ...
}
```