# Java & C++: Not identical timezone (Windows Embedded Compact + Handheld)

Tags: java, c++, timezone

My C++ program sets a timezone using method SetTimeZoneInformation() with values:

- StandardName = "Central Europe Standard Time"
- DaylightName = "Central Europe Daylight Time"
- Bias = -60

It can then be easily read by C++ method GetTimeZoneInformation(). Demo can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724944(v=vs.85).aspx):

But if I try to read this information by Java using this code:

```
TimeZone timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
```

... it shows a different value:

- timeZone.getID() returns "GMT"
- timeZone.getDisplayName() returns "Greenwich Mean Time"

It seems that both methods work with different data or they interpret it differently.

The same situation occurs when I change the timezone manually using windows-ui. Even if I select timezone "Hawaii" in Windows, Java still returns "GMT", while C++ retuns correct value "Hawaiian Standard Time". List of these textual IDs can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx).

Do you have some experiences with both languages, please? Where does C++ write the info and where does it Java read from? Can I somehow propagate the timezone from Win to Java and visa versa?

Comment: Java default timezone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly.

Comment: Thanks, now I wanted to paste the same link, but it does not solve my situation. I cannot pass parameters to my Java program during startup, I need to dynamically change the timezone in C++ or Java and use it immediately in the other environment.

Comment: Another link to similar topis is here. It says that there is some bug in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106525/java-incorrect-timezone

Comment: In case Java's standard library has a bug, you can look for (or write) a library yourself that at least retrieves the correct timezone so you can set it programmatically in Java.

Comment: So I found out that it may work, but our Java had a problem when current timezone was using "Daylight saving time" (summer time). If it was used in the current timezone, Java returned GMT instead.